# $f(n) = 2^n - 1.41^n$ - exponential growth?

Tags: number-theory

Does $f(n) = 2^n - 1.41^n$ grow exponentially?

Can anyone prove or disprove it?

If not, what degree can it be a polynomial?

Comment: What is your definition of exponential growth? Have you tried to apply it?

Comment: Mistake. I update. The question of whether growth is exponential. Is this an exponential function in the big O notation..

Comment: For $n \gt 2$ this is less than $2^n$ and less than $e^n$ but more than $1.41^n$

Comment: How does $f(n)/2^n$ behave as $n\to\infty$?

Comment: Use $f(n)=2^n(1-a^n)$ with $a=\frac{1.41}2<1$ hence $a^n\to0$ and $\frac{f(n)}{2^n}\to1$.

Comment: Divide your function by an exponentially-growing function, specifically $(1.41)^n$, to obtain $(2/1.41)^n-1$, which is still exponentially growing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$f_n = 1.41^n\left(\left(\frac{2}{1.41}\right)^n - 1\right)$$